# convert string in Dataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a weird .txt and convert it to a weird dataframe.

This is the txt.

```
,image_path,label,nose,neck,r_sho,r_elb,r_wri,l_sho,l_elb,l_wri,r_hip,r_knee,r_ank,l_hip,l_knee,l_ank,r_eye,l_eye,r_ear,l_ear
0,/home/karantai/Desktop/fall_detection/fall-06-cam0-rgb-040.png,0,[283 311],[283 382],[275 423],[290 307],[283 375],[241 431],[350 375],[313 446],[410 431],[376 356],[373 397],[451 416],[-1 -1],[238 307],[-1 -1],[256 292],,
```

The [x y] data are string and I want to convert them to np.array. Is there a way by reading them in a specific way, or converting them after reading?

Comment: if you were to do it, how would you do it? Would you use functions to read from text? Would you `eval` it to a list? would you remove the square brackets and `replace` the space by commas?

Comment: I want to convert this string [283 311] to array. I need to replace whitespace to comma and afterwards to numpy array somehow

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expression:

```
import re
m = re.findall(r"\[\d+ \d+\]", txt)
m
```

The partial output is a list of strings:

```
['[283 311]', '[283 382]', '[275 423]', '[290 307]', '[283 375]',
'[241 431]', '[350 375]', '[313 446]', '[410 431]', '[376 356]',
'[373 397]', '[451 416]', '[238 307]', '[256 292]']
```

Then you make a list comprhension:

```
[[int(row[1:4]), int(row[5:8])] for row in m]
```

The output is:

```
[[283, 311], [283, 382], [275, 423], [290, 307], [283, 375], [241, 431],
[350, 375], [313, 446], [410, 431], [376, 356], [373, 397], [451, 416],
[238, 307], [256, 292]]
```